# How to infer the consequence of a function being one-one in this question ? (See details)

Tags: calculus, functions, trigonometry, proof-explanation

From my problem book:

> Let $f: X \to Y$ be a function defined by $f(x) = a \sin\left(x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right) + b \cos (x) + c.$ Also $f$ is both one-one and onto, find the sets $X,Y.$

> Solution: Given $f(x)=a \sin \left(x+\frac{\pi}{4}\right)+b \cos x+c=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} a \sin x+\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}+b\right) \cos x+c$ $=r \sin (x+\theta)+c,$
>
> where $r=\sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}+\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{2}}+b\right)^{2}}$ and $\theta=\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{a+\sqrt{2} b}{a}\right) .$
>
> **Since** $f$ **is one-one, then we can write** $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x+\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2}.$,
> $\Rightarrow-\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta \leq x \leq \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta, x \in\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta, \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right]$, i.e., $X=\left[-\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta, \frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right]$
>
> $\ldots$

My question: Why does $f$ being one-one allow $-\frac{\pi}{2} \leq x+\theta \leq \frac{\pi}{2} \: ?$

I know that if $f(x) = f(y)$  implies $x=y$, then $f$ is one-one but I fail to see how this relates to the problem.

P.S. On a side note, if I am allowed to ask a separate small question, Why are we interested in the representation as $r \sin (x + \alpha)$ in the first place ?

Comment: is there a missing condition? what if X={0} and Y={a/sqrt(2)+b+c}? or X has length $\pi$?

Comment: @cineel no other condition is mentioned in the book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** The question the book is asking doesn't really make sense. There is more than one possible solution for $X$, so asking for "the set $X$" is misleading. We can ask for "**a** set $X$".

In order for just the function $\sin(x)$ to be one-to-one, we need to put a restriction on it's domain. We have many choices for this, but the one most often used is restricting the domain to $-\frac\pi2\leq x\leq \frac\pi2$.

Now, we have $f(x)=r\sin(x+\theta)+c$. In order for this to be one-to-one, we need to restrict the inputs of $\sin$, so, just like above, we can restrict it to $-\frac\pi2\leq x+\theta\leq \frac\pi2$.

In regards to your second question, we are interested in the above representation because it allows us to restrict the domain easily.

Comment: Do we restrict the domain of $\sin (x)$ due to it being periodic and to make it one-to-one we need to have distinct input-output pairs (which the periodic nature wouldn't allow) ?

Comment: Yes. That's exactly what we do with $\sin(x)$ to allow it to be invertible to $\sin^{-1}(x)$.